# How to sum total of subtotal that at the list in appery io

Tags: javascript, appery.io

How to add up all the subtotal in the following picture, this subtotal in on the table list and it run buy array. When I add up a product it will update a new list

I found a lot of solutions on Google but none of them fixed my problem. I have to add up this by using array sum method or run by database query?

Here is some code I have:

```
var DB_id = request.get("5655c24fe4b0c14e6b3c1623"), 
    collectionName='Cart', 
    columnName = 'subtotal'; 
query = Collection.query(DB_id, collectionName); 
var i, len, value, sum = 0; 
for(i = 0, len = query.length; i < len; i++) { 
    value = parseInt(query[i][columnName]); 
    sum += value; 
} 
Apperyio('total').text('RM'+sum.toFixed(2));
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask here. Hint: Post some code

Comment: var DB_id = request.get("5655c24fe4b0c14e6b3c1623"),
collectionName='Cart',
columnName = 'subtotal';

  query = Collection.query(DB_id, collectionName);
  var i, len, value, sum = 0;
  for(i = 0, len = query.length; i < len; i++) {
    value = parseInt(query[i][columnName]);

      sum += value;
  }
  Apperyio('total').text('RM'+sum.toFixed(2));

Comment: This is my code for sum uo all the subtotal in the list

Comment: Next time add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of Appery.io [Server Code](https://docs.appery.io/reference/servercode-collection-query). But you write it with the client-side code `Apperyio('total').text('RM'+sum.toFixed(2));`, so it is not correct. Please move it to the Server Code and call it from your application. In this case, you can return the total sum with a simple mapping. So your final code will be:

```
var DB_id = request.get("5655c24fe4b0c14e6b3c1623"), 
collectionName='Cart', 
columnName = 'subtotal'; 
    query = Collection.query(DB_id, collectionName); 
    var i, len, value, sum = 0; 
for(i = 0, len = query.length; i < len; i++) { 
    value = parseInt(query[i][columnName]); 
    sum += value; 
} 
Apperyio.response.success({"sum": sum}, "application/json");
```